# How to implement save() and update() method in grails api resource

Tags: rest, api, grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 1.3.7 version for my application. I trying to write a rest api for my existing application. So that, I can develop the mobile apps for the applications. But problem is, I couldn't find a good rest client for 1.3.7. I am using JSON-rest-api plugin but I am not sure how I can implement save() and update() for my resource controller.Also I can't upgrade the grails version for now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again everybody.

Comment: Could you show your code and provide more details where exactly you found a problem?

Comment: I just add the plugin and it is working. But i need some rest client plugins which actually work with grails 1.3.7.